# Why PHP_CodeSniffer shows errors No response from codesniffer?

Tags: phpstorm, phpcodesniffer

In PhpStorm 2021.1 working with Laravel 9 I have
`"squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.7.1"` installed and periodically I got errors

> No response from codesniffer :

[image]

But I have PHP_CodeSniffer installed and checked it is installed and activated.

Any hints how these errors could be fixed?

Comment: Are you using local or remote interpreter to run phpcs?

Comment: Localy on my home kubuntu 20

Comment: So there's no Docker/vagrant involved? Then we need to check IDE logs & your project. The most convenient way to do this is to contact us (PhpStorm support) via Help | Contact Support.

Comment: Where can I find/check IDE logs  ? Under IDE? some files under user/home  ? What have I to pay attention at  ?

Comment: You can run Help > Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data and send over the resulting archive using Help | Contact Support to begin with.